# Basic XSLT issue - just want to select a couple of values and nothing else

Tags: xslt

Could someone please tell me the XSLT I need to get the output "LIVE|Customer is active" from the XML below. I thought I had the answer from another post but turned out not.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cns:customer xmlns:cns="https://services.cns.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://services.cns.com docs/xsd/customer.xsd">
    <cns:userId>1001</cns:userId>
    <cns:status>LIVE</cns:status>
    <cns:statusMessage>Customer is active</cns:statusMessage>
    <cns:type wholesale="true" suspended="false">W1</cns:type>
    <cns:properties>
        <cns:property>
            <cns:name>Name</cns:name>
            <cns:value>Bob</cns:value>
        </cns:property>
    </cns:properties>
</cns:customer>
```

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to convert the XML to the string mentioned in your question, the following stylesheet can be used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:cns="https://services.cns.com">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(cns:status,'|',cns:statusMessage)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I didn't really want the namespace in the solution, but I've been playing around with XSLT and this seems to do the trick `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='customer']">
     <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='status']/text()"/>
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#124;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='statusMessage']/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: Don't sprinkle your code with disable-output-escaping as if it were magic fairy dust. It's a powerful and dangerous feature, it doesn't work in all environments, and by using it with method="text" you show that you don't understand it: with method="text" there is no escaping that needs to be disabled.